# Support projection of a normal state

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $\rho$ a normal state on $M$.

Suppose that $a$ is  in the centralizer of $\rho$ and $b$ is positive in $M$ such that $abs(\rho)=0$, where $s(\rho)$ is the support projection of $\rho$.

Can we conclude that $ab=0$?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Comment: "Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community" - not on these tags.

Comment: As it's stated, that's even wrong for $M=\mathbb C^2$. Are you sure you are not missing any assumptions?

Comment: @MaoWao. I thought it has a general conclusion. Actually, the original statement is as following : Suppose $\rho$ is a normal state on $M$, $a\in M_{\rho}$, if we have $a^{\frac{1}{2}}xa^{\frac{1}{2}}s(\rho)=0(x\geq 0)$, then $ax=0$.

Comment: But this still does not help. Take $M=\mathbb C^2$, $\rho(x_1,x_2)=x_1$, $a=(0,1)$, $x=(1,1)$, then $ax=(0,1)\neq 0$, but $a^{1/2}xa^{1/2}s(\rho)=(0,1)(1,0)=0$.

Comment: $\rho_A(x) = {\lim}_{\epsilon \to 0} \rho(A_\epsilon^{1/2} x A_\epsilon^{1/2})\quad (x\in M^+),$ where $A_\epsilon:= A(1+\epsilon A)^{-1}\in M_\rho$ for $\epsilon >0$.  If for any $\epsilon >0$, we have $A_\epsilon^{1/2} x A_\epsilon^{1/2}=0$,  how to conclude that $xA_\epsilon=0$?